# how to match value in file1 with value in file2 & get relevant info to add in file1?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have 2 files, first row is a header row for reference

- `file1`

  ```
  userId  userContact parentId  parentContact
  200     0900200     100       -
  201     0900201     100       -
  300     0900300     101       -
  ```
- `file2`

  ```
  userId  userContact parentId  parentContact
  100     0900100     100       -
  101     0900101     100       -
  ```

I want to populate 4th column of `file1`, so that it has to search `$3` of `file1` in `$1` of `file2`, and then bring `$2` from `file2` in place of `$4` of `file1`
so output should look like this:

- `output`

  ```
  userId  userContact parentId  parentContact
  200     0900200     100       0900100
  201     0900201     100       0900100
  300     0900300     101       0900101
  ```

I'd prefer `awk`, as it will be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR { keep[$1] = $2 ; next};
       FNR==1 {print;next};
       { $4 = keep[$3]; print }' file2 file1
userId  userContact parentId  parentContact
200 0900200 100 0900100
201 0900201 100 0900100
300 0900300 101 0900101
```

This reads in `file2`, storing field 2 of each line in an array called `keep` (indexed by the value of field 1).  Once it has finished reading `file2`, it starts reading `file1`.  It prints the first line (header line), then for each subsequent input line it changes field 4 to the value in `keep[$3]` and prints it.

The script detects whether it is reading `file2` or not with the `NR==FNR` test.  awk's `FNR` variable contains the current line number of the current file, while `NR` contains the cumulative total line number of all files read so far.  So, if FNR is equal to NR, we are reading the first file (i.e. `file2` - which is why it has to be listed as the first filename arg).   There are some fairly obscure circumstances where this test doesn't work terribly well, but it's fine for most circumstances (including this one).

If you need to change the input or output field separators, you can use awk's -F and -v options.  e.g. `-F'\t'` and/or `-v OFS='\t'`.

Answer (score 5):

Using `join` (it requires sorted input files, so we passed sorted inputs).

```
join -1 3 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.2 <(sort -k3 file1) <(sort file2)
200 0900200 100 0900100
201 0900201 100 0900100
300 0900300 101 0900101
```

With `-1 3`, join selecets the 3<sup>rd</sup> column as the key from the first input file (file1), and with `-2 1` selects the 1<sup>st</sup> column as the key from the second input file (file2); then it `-o`utputs these columns *<file#>.<column#>*.

If your inputs are Tab delimited files, add `-t$'\t'` to the join command as well as to the `sort -k3 file1`.
if you wanted header line to be printed then add `head -n1 file1;` before the join.

---

Or with using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ parentId[$1]=$2; next }
     FNR>1  { $4=parentId[$3] }1' file2 file1
```